# »TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange requires external JavaScript from another domain, which is blocked or failed to load.«

Tags: discussion, javascript

I'm browsing with firefox, but to minimise risks I use an addon called »NoScript«. I reconfigured it today, because too many sites recognise me. Now I get the message you can read in the headline, as well as here in Meta: »TeX - LaTeX Meta Stack Exchange requires external JavaScript from another domain, which is blocked or failed to load.«

I'm glad that TeX.se exists. But wouldn't it be better style not to have all that zoo (google-analytics, googleapis, quantserve and the like)? StackExchange really seems able to provide those services themselves!?

Comment: This is a cross-network thing, so you might get more info on meta.SO

Comment: I recommend using `ghostery`+`adblockplus` instead. It involves blocking the trackers instead of blocking scripts.

Comment: @percusse I googled ghostery and the funny thing is they provide an address downtown Manhattan -- not the cheapest area on this planet -- but no information on how they earn money. A magazin in Germany published a kind of warning.

Comment: @KeksDose I don't know why it matters but Downtown Manhattan is not a uniformly rich place like Beverly Hills and address doesn't say anything about the revenue. Also what did the magazine say? If I turn on google analytics on my webpages or my friends' other tracked websites and then use ghostery and access those sites we don't see me accessing the sites. So it is functional but of course they might be the devil too there is no end to being suspicious.

Comment: Oh and rich people can do good things too you know :)

Answer (score 11):

With NoScript extension, to use TeX.se, you must enable `stackexchange.com`, `sstatic.net` (from stackexchange network) and `googleapis.com` (common javascript libraries).

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what these libraries are good for?

Comment: @strpeter `googleapis.com` provides the jQuery library. This open source library is good for... javascript programming.